# What does it mean: SQL state: 42703 Context: Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query

Tags: postgresql

I tried to create exactly the same but new table from old table in another database using dblink. This procedure used to worked last two times, but this time I got message:
"SQL state: 42703
Context: Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query."

Anyone knows where is the problem or how to solve it?
Please!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this problem and fixed it by using single quotes, rather than double quotes, for the string I was searching for:

```
select * from table where column = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of possible causes:

http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-206_sqlstate_42703.html

Best to catch the query before it is executed, then you will be able to see what exactly the problem is.  If you post it here, we can help you further.

Comment: And by the way, I tried exactly the same query just with new name of new table, and the result is still the same as I mentioned above...Maybe a bug?!?!?

Comment: Unlikely to be a bug, if you paste the actual SQL query into here that you are trying to execute it would be more helpful

Comment: The above link seems unlikely to be relevant. Its for DB2 right? But the question is about postgres.